# jQuery Traversing in the DOM with Next() or Find()

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I am having problem with Traversing in the DOM.

`<div class="dropdown-left">
  <ul>
    <li>
        Parent 1
        <ul class="dropdown-right">
            <ul class="dropdown-right-col1">
              <li>Test 1</li>
              <li>Test 2</li>
              <li>Test 3</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Parent 2
        <ul class="dropdown-right">
            <ul class="dropdown-right-col1">
              <li>TEST 4</li>
              <li>TEST 5</li>
              <li>TEST 6</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>`

jQuery show result with this code. It found all `ul.dropdown-right` and I only want it to found the children instead.

```
$(".dropdown-left").bind('click', "li", function() {
    $(this).find("ul.dropdown-right").slideToggle(150);
```

This is the code I was want to use but it won't show any result.

```
$(".dropdown-left").bind('click', "li", function() {
    $(this).next("ul.dropdown-right").slideToggle(150);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is .dropdown-left in your HTML?

Comment: `.next` only selects siblings. I think you mean `$(this).next().find("ul.dropdown-right").slideToggle(150);`

Comment: Sorry, I think this is my fault. I tried the code and it didn't work:( I clarify the DOM just now. Would you mind take a look at it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this functionality:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-left").bind('click', function() {
    $(this).children('ul.dropdown-right').slideToggle(150);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown-left">
      Parent 1
      <ul class="dropdown-right">
        <ul class="dropdown-right-col1">
          <li>Test 1</li>
          <li>Test 2</li>
          <li>Test 3</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-left">
      Parent 2
      <ul class="dropdown-right">
        <ul class="dropdown-right-col1">
          <li>TEST 4</li>
          <li>TEST 5</li>
          <li>TEST 6</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think this is my fault. I tried the code and it didn't work:( I clarify the DOM just now. Would you mind take a look at it again. Thanks!